# How to set string render method for a class in Python

Tags: python, string, class

If I do:

```
    print "The item is:" + str(1) + "."
```

I will get:

```
    The item is 1.
```

But if I use an object of my class, dbref (here x is one of it), and try to stringify it:

```
    print "The item is:" + str(x) + "."
```

I will get:

```
    The item is <mufdatatypes.dbref instance at 0xb74a2bec>.
```

I'd rather it return a string of my own design. Is there a function I can define within my class that will let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a string from [the `__str__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). Like so:

```
class SomeClass(object):

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __str__(self):
    return '<SomeClass %s>' % self.value
```

Comment: Ok, this works up until it's nested in a list. Is there any way to make sure that, when the item is inside of a list, it is also given the same representation when that list is printed?

Comment: You actually don't want that, but `__repr__()` controls the representation of the object.

Comment: Use a list comprehension: [str(x) for x in yourlist] .. Unless you think you can maintain the invariant `eval(x.__repr__()) == x`

Comment: Why do I need to maintain that?

Comment: You don't need to, it's just convenient and desirable if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Define a `__str__` method.

```
>>> class Spam(object):
...   def __str__(self):
...     """my custom string representation"""
...     return 'spam, spam, spam and eggs'
... 
>>> x = Spam()
>>> x
<__main__.Spam object at 0x1519bd0>
>>> print(x)
spam, spam, spam and eggs
>>> print("The item is:" + str(x) + ".")
The item is:spam, spam, spam and eggs.
>>> print("The item is: {}".format(x))
The item is: spam, spam, spam and eggs
```

Below is a demonstration of why you probably [don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799493/how-to-set-string-render-method-for-a-class-in-python#comment12479107_9799527) to use `__repr__` to over-ride representation of your item in a list or other container:

```
>>> class mystr(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return str(self)
... 
>>> x = ['this list ', 'contains', '3 elements']
>>> print(x)
['this list ', 'contains', '3 elements']
>>> x = [mystr('this list, also'), mystr('contains'), mystr('3 elements')]
>>> print(x)
[this list, also, contains, 3 elements]
```